# SSH login shows Only console users are allowed to run the X server

Tags: ssh, zsh, tmux, archlinux, xorg

Every time I log in from SSH, I get:

> Only console users are allowed to run the X server

I also get this if I make a new `tmux` pane, which I can handle by putting:

`test -z ${TMUX} && startx`

in my `.zprofile`

I assume I get the message because I run `startx`.
How can I make it not to run `startx` if I log in from ssh?

Comment: Check the existence of the `$SSH_CONNECTION` env var.

Comment: Perhaps the answer to [this Unix & Linux question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout) can help: notice the mention of `.zlogin` for starting X-windows.

Comment: **ATTENTION:** `tmux` for some reason calls `.bash_profile` which should only be executed on login! This is wrong ! And this is why if you have `startx` or `xinit openbox-session` or any similar lines that starts X server in your `.bash_profile`, you have to edit them like this `test -z ${TMUX} && startx` or `test -z ${TMUX} && xinit openbox-session` to prevent `tmux` to again open X server. If that would happen everything would crash. You can test this crash if you open `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and change `alowed_users=console` to `allowed_users=anybody` and then start `tmux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a solution for this, that is by login automatically right after booting by using `xlogin` and `dbus`.

Here is a wiki of how to do that:

[Automatic login into xorg without display manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_login_into_Xorg_without_display_manager)